# Using native wp image support instead of timthumb

Tags: core, timthumb

After having no luck with timthumb, and on the advice from this site I am going to edit my theme so it works using native wp functions. However I'm a little stuck.

I found this http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/1098

Which appears to be a function which will resize images on the fly, but I'm not totally sure how to use it in my theme.

In addition to that, I know there is the normal thumbnails feature in WP - but how would I use that instead of timthumb which currently is just a url in my image source?

Answer (score 1):

In your theme you need to `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` and then set up some `add_image_size();`

By doing this in your themes functions file you'll get have support for the built in Feature images and any image sizes you set up images will be generated in the correct size.

For more information on setting up images sizes the codex offers:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size